# DeepLearning4j k-means very slow

Tags: java, multithreading, k-means, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I'm trying to use DL4J's K-Means implementation. I set it up as follows:

```
int CLUSTERS = 5;
int MAX_ITERATIONS = 300;
String DISTANCE_METRIC = "cosinesimilarity";
KMeansClustering KMEANS = KMeansClustering.setup(CLUSTERS, MAX_ITERATIONS, DISTANCE_METRIC);
```

My data points are vectors of size 300 (doubles), and my test set is comprised of ~ 100 data points each time (give or take). I'm running it on my CPU (4 cores) in a single threaded fashion.

Evaluation takes a very long time (a few seconds per example).

I took a peek inside the algorithm's implementation and it looks like its concurrency level is very high - a lot of threads are being created (one per data point, to be exact) and executed in parallel.
Perhaps this is an overkill?
Is there any way I can control it through configuration? Other ways to speed it up? If not, is there any other fast java-based solution for executing k-means?

Comment: Mind filing an issue? https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

We don't heavily maintain that kmeans. We can at least take a look at some point though. You should probably expect to send a pull request though.

Comment: Issue has been filed:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues/4234
I could try and improve the situation if I get some guidance. 10x

Answer (score 0):

"DL4J supports GPUs and is compatible with distributed computing software such as Apache Spark and Hadoop." from https://deeplearning4j.org

Extra Spark or Hadoop instance might help for scaling performance.

Comment: Hi, this is actually wrong. There are spark implementations of these different algorithms. The old kmeans you see here, is a simpler implementation that uses a single box. Beyond that, we did a recent pass on kmeans.